# Mockito InvalidUseOfMatchersException while mocking an Interface/Abstract class

Tags: java, maven, mockito, surefire

I recently upgrade Maven Surefire plugin to version v2.14.1 (from v2.6) in my project. After this upgrade Mockito started throwing InvalidUseOfMatchersException in all JUnit tests where a Mockito.mock() method is invoked on an 'interface' or 'abstract class'. Same Unit Test works fine when executed through Eclipse, but always fails while building with Maven.

```
 Here are few examples of calls that are failing:

 i) DataSource dataSource = Mockito.mock(DataSource.class);

ii) DatabaseMetaData metaData = mock(DatabaseMetaData.class);

iii) ResultSet rs = mock(ResultSet.class);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InvalidUseOfMatchersException` is almost never caused by a call to `Mockito.mock()`; rather, the call to `Mockito.mock()` tells Mockito to [validate that it's not in the middle of something](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/MockingProgressImpl.java?name=1.9.5#117), which is when it determines that it should throw a `InvalidUseOfMatchersException`. Your error is probably related to Maven/Surefire because it's executing your test methods in a different order than Eclipse does, or because Maven is reusing a JVM where Eclipse isn't.

Mockito matchers are static functions that return dummy values (but that secretly log their calls with Mockito). Internally, Mockito keeps [a stack of previously-called matchers](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/source/browse/src/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorageImpl.java?name=1.9.5#26), one per thread, so if you call a Matcher at the end of a test method it will linger around to pollute the next test method in the same thread.

The easiest way to pin this down is to put a call to [`Mockito.validateMockitoUsage()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage()) in your `tearDown` method (JUnit3) or an `@After` method (JUnit4). That will cause the test method that misuses Mockito to fail there, rather than in whatever next method that runs.

As for the actual Matcher misuse? Double-check that every time you use a Matcher from `org.mockito.Mockito` or `org.mockito.Matchers`, you're actually matching every single argument in the function; I went over the reasons in a [separate SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15698493/1426891). Be particularly wary of calling other mocks from within your calls to `when` or `verify` (which interferes with Mockito's static magic) or when trying to stub or verify any method marked `final` (which will fail silently because the VM calls the actual implementation instead).

Hope that helps!

Comment: A very clear answer.  It's also worth noting that you might consider using the `MockitoJUnitRunner`, which automatically calls `initMocks()` at the start of each test and `validateMockitoUsage()` at the end of each test.

Comment: I like your detailed explanation. Actually error message in this case was very misleading. Since those JUnits always worked with Surefire 2.6 and suddenly started failing on Interface/Abstract classes with Surefire 2.14.1, I decided to downgrade Surefire gradually (one point version at a time) to figure out which version it starts breaking with. It first broke with v2.12.4, but the exception trace with v2.12.4 was a lot clearer than v2.14.1, it pointed to a different Test class. After I fixed that class everything worked fine with latest version of Surefire.