# Mockito exception : org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException

Tags: java, mockito

I have this code:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

final Combobox combobox = mock(Combobox.class);

//.... some business logic which calls method 'appendChild' on 'combobox'

verify(combobox, times(3)).appendChild((Component) anyObject()); // <<== exception here
```

And it writes all the time this:

```
Invalid use of argument matchers!
2 matchers expected, 1 recorded.
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
//incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher")); 
For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

appendChild method looks like this:

```
public final boolean appendChild(Component child)
{
     return insertBfr(null, child);
}
```

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Please post your SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) here.

Comment: Is there different versions (with different number of arguments) of the method `appendChild`? Could you show us the code of this method?

Comment: Why are you using `anyObject`?  Use `any` with your class in the generic instead.  See what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendChild` is a final method, which means [you can't mock or verify it](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/wiki/FAQ#What_are_the_limitations_of_Mockito). The Java compiler understands "final" to mean that it can be sure which actual method implementation it's calling, which means it take a shortcut to call that code directly rather than allowing Mockito to sneak in and replace the implementation. In general, this is one of the good reasons people recommend [*not to mock types you don't own or control*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1906344/1426891).

Refactor your test, or use [PowerMockito](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13) to perform deep bytecode magic to mock those final methods.

(*Why that exception?* Matchers [actually affect static state in Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22822514/1426891). Because you call `anyObject` on that line, Mockito still [registers a Matcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15698493/1426891). That Matcher matches a nonexistent argument on your next call to `when` or `verify`, or gets caught by [the Mockito usage validator](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage()) if you use [`MockitoJUnitRunner`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/runners/MockitoJUnitRunner.html). Either way, it's a good catch, because the code doesn't do what you think it does.)