# Throw a RuntimeException when invoking an unstubbed method

Tags: java, mockito

I'm using Mockito. I want to throw a `RuntimeException` when an unstubbed method is called.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "unmocked method" in this context? All methods in a class are mocked when using `mock(...)`/`@Mock`.

Comment: Because I often forget to mock some methods. Exceptions can help find these methods.

Comment: So your proposition is that you want to have all void methods in a (mocked) class throw an exception?

Comment: But if I didn't handle method of mock object than this method return null (if it must return Object)

Comment: I think he means all methods that have not been stubbed.

Comment: See [Issue 346: Answers.THROWS_EXCEPTION](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/issues/detail?id=346) for a ticket to add this behaviour to Mockito.

Comment: It's kind of baffling that this isn't the default behaviour!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can set a default answer for a mock. All methods that aren't stubbed will use this default answer.

```
public void testUnstubbedException() {
    // Create a mock with all methods throwing a RuntimeException by default
    SomeClass someClass = mock( SomeClass .class, new RuntimeExceptionAnswer() );

    doReturn(1).when(someClass).getId(); // Must use doReturn

    int id = someClass.getId(); // Will return 1

    someClass.unstubbedMethod(); // Will throw RuntimeException
}

public static class RuntimeExceptionAnswer implements Answer<Object> {

    public Object answer( InvocationOnMock invocation ) throws Throwable {
        throw new RuntimeException ( invocation.getMethod().getName() + " is not stubbed" );
    }

}
```

Note that you **cannot** use `when` with this functionality, since the method is called before `when` ([How does mockito when() invocation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440270/how-does-mockito-when-invocation-work)) and it will throw a `RuntimeException` before the mock goes into stubbing mode.

Therefore, you must use `doReturn` for this to work.

Comment: it's too bad this requires `doReturn` and a little extra work than one would expect for such a common desire

Comment: I have a bunch of tests already implemented by someone else.  Now the tests are failing because new methods added classes are not mocked, but I don't konw which ones since they simply return a null.  I would like to set up all the methods that are NOT mocked to throw an exception.  Requiring that I rewrite all the `when` functions to `doReturn` is a lot of rewrite I don't want to do.

Answer (score 15):

The best way to do this is with the `verifyNoMoreInteractions` and `ignoreStubs` static methods.  Call these after the "act" part of your test; and you'll get a failure if any unstubbed methods were called but not verified.

```
verifyNoMoreInteractions(ignoreStubs(myMock));
```

This is described at https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.47/org/mockito/Mockito.html#ignore_stubs_verification although I believe that the code example there currently contains a misprint.

Comment: This doesn't help if your test has crashed obscurely before this point due to a null dereference caused by a call to an unmocked method.

Comment: This solution only works if the null does not get dereferenced, while Guillaume Berche's solution only works if the the null does get dereferenced. By combining the two solutions, one can cover both cases.

Comment: @Zoltan Can you clarify what you mean please?  Neither the question nor my solution say anything at all about a null; so I can't make sense of your assertion that my solution only works if the null doesn't get dereferenced.  What null?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: Unstubbed methods of a mock return null by default (or 0 or false). David Given commented above that adding `verifyNoMorInteraction` to the end of the test cases does not help diagnose accidentally unstubbed methods if they cause a null pointer exception earlier. Guillaume Berche posted an answer that provides a much more useful failure message when this happens using "smart" nulls, but it doesn't help with the case when the (smart) null does not get dereferenced. It seems to me that the combination of the two answers covers all bases.

Comment: I think it goes without saying that a particular line of code won't run if you dereference a null immediately beforehand.  But thanks for elaborating on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Refinement over Tom's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/15835255/1484823

Mockito now provides builtin support with a default answer which throws exception, and can be specified either with @Mock annotation

```
    @Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_SMART_NULLS)
    private BackingAppDeploymentService backingAppDeploymentService;
```

or

```
    private BackingAppDeploymentService  backingAppDeploymentService =
      Mockito.mock(BackingAppDeploymentService.class, new ReturnsSmartNulls());
```

See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_SMART_NULLS

> If your code uses the object returned by an unstubbed call you get a NullPointerException. This implementation of Answer returns SmartNull instead of null. SmartNull gives nicer exception message than NPE because it points out the line where unstubbed method was called. You just click on the stack trace.
>
> ReturnsSmartNulls first tries to return ordinary values (zeros, empty collections, empty string, etc.) then it tries to return SmartNull. If the return type is final then plain null is returned.
>
> ReturnsSmartNulls will be probably the default return values strategy in Mockito 4.0.0

Comment: This is not what was asked. You are not getting a runtime exception if the "smart null" returned is never used. So, this does not answer the question that was about "getting an exception when forgetting to mock a method"

Comment: SmartNulls do not solve the problem.  I want to know if a method is being called in the runtime of my program on an object that has been mocked, but for which the method have not been provided.  Default behavior is to return a null which is legitimate in some cases.  I want an EXCEPTION thrown because whatever this method call returns is NOT a valid response, and I want to be informed of that so I can fix it.

Comment: This solution only works if the null does get dereferenced, while Dawood ibn Kareem's solution only works if the the null does not get dereferenced. By combining the two solutions, one can cover both cases.

Answer (score -1):

You mock an entire class and the result is that all methods will return null.

Then you can use `doReturn(...)` to change that behavior. Similarly, you can use `doThrow(...)` to make (as I recall only `void`) methods throw exceptions.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: I think he wants to make sure that all methods are mocked, for example that Mockito throws an exception if a method have not been mocked

Comment: Yes! But I want to make sure that all methods that will be invoked are mocked.

Comment: All methods in a mocked class _are_ mocked - by definition.

Comment: Awesome! I want that if I did not handle method (like this 'when(mockedObj.getName()).thanReturn("ebala")' ) then method throw RuntimeException when it will be invoked.

Comment: That's called stubbing, not mocking :)

Comment: Thanks for word 'stubbing')