# android testing - mockito error org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito, mvp

I try to create test for my presenter, but when I run it, I got this kind of error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
ScalarSynchronousObservable cannot be returned by getContext()
getContext() should return Context
```

I create my presenter test class like this

```
public class CreateTalkPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    TalkService talkService;

    @Mock
    CreateTalkMvpView createTalkMvpView;

    CreateTalkPresenter createTalkPresenter;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        talkService = ServiceFactory.createMapi(createTalkMvpView.getContext(), TalkService.class);
        createTalkPresenter = new CreateTalkPresenter(Schedulers.immediate(), Schedulers.immediate());
        createTalkPresenter.attachView(createTalkMvpView);
    }

    @Test
    public void createTalkSuccessfullTest() {
        TalkService.TalkResultModel talkResultModel = MockModel.newTalkResultModel();

        when(talkService.createNewTalk(
                FileUtil.createPartFromString("Lorem Ipsum dolor"),
                FileUtil.createPartFromString("100"),
                null,
                FileUtil.createPartFromString("0")
        )).thenReturn(Observable.just(talkResultModel));

        createTalkPresenter.callCreateTalk("Lorem Ipsum dolor", "100", null);

        verify(createTalkMvpView).showProgressIndeterminate();
        verify(createTalkMvpView).hideProgressIndeterminate();
        verify(createTalkMvpView).showTalkCreated(talkResultModel.object);
    }
}
```

and for Mock the result I use this class

```
public class MockModel {

    public static TalkService.TalkResultModel newTalkResultModel(){
        TalkService.TalkResultModel talkResultModel = new TalkService.TalkResultModel();
        talkResultModel.code = 600;
        talkResultModel.message = "Successfully executed!";
        talkResultModel.object = newTalkModel();

        return talkResultModel;
    }

    public static TalkModel newTalkModel(){
        Random random = new Random();
        String index = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100));
        TalkModel talkModel = new TalkModel();
        talkModel.id = index;
        talkModel.content = "Lorem Ipsum dolor";
        talkModel.categorytalk = newCategoryTalkModel("Category "+index);
        talkModel.creator = newConsumerModel("User "+index);
        return talkModel;
    }

    public static CategoryTalkModel newCategoryTalkModel(String name){
        CategoryTalkModel categoryTalkModel = new CategoryTalkModel();
        categoryTalkModel.id = "100";
        categoryTalkModel.name = name;
        return categoryTalkModel;
    }

    public static ConsumerModel newConsumerModel(String name){
        Random random = new Random();
        String index = String.valueOf(random.nextInt(100));
        ConsumerModel consumerModel = new ConsumerModel();
        consumerModel.id = index;
        consumerModel.username = name;
        consumerModel.email = name+"@domain.com";
        consumerModel.fullName = "Fullname "+name;
        return consumerModel;
    }
}
```

And this is the presenter class that I want to test

```
public class CreateTalkPresenter implements Presenter<CreateTalkMvpView> {

    private CreateTalkMvpView createTalkMvpView;
    private TalkService mApiTalkService;
    private TalkService.TalkResultModel talkResultModel;
    private final Scheduler mainScheduler, ioScheduler;

    private Subscription subscription;

    public CreateTalkPresenter(Scheduler ioScheduler, Scheduler mainScheduler) {
        this.ioScheduler = ioScheduler;
        this.mainScheduler = mainScheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public void attachView(CreateTalkMvpView view) {
        createTalkMvpView = view;
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        createTalkMvpView = null;
        unsubscribe();
    }

    private void unsubscribe() {
        if (subscription != null) subscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    public void callCreateTalk(String content, String categoryId, String filePath) {
        mApiTalkService = ServiceFactory.createMapi(createTalkMvpView.getContext(), TalkService.class);

        unsubscribe();
        createTalkMvpView.showProgressIndeterminate();
        subscription = mApiTalkService.createNewTalk(
                FileUtil.createPartFromString(content),
                FileUtil.createPartFromString(categoryId),
                filePath != null ? FileUtil.prepareFilePart("picture", new File(filePath)) : null,
                FileUtil.createPartFromString("0"))
                .observeOn(mainScheduler)
                .subscribeOn(ioScheduler)
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<TalkService.TalkResultModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        createTalkMvpView.hideProgressIndeterminate();
                        createTalkMvpView.showTalkCreated(talkResultModel.object);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        createTalkMvpView.hideProgressIndeterminate();
                        WarningUtil.onApiError(createTalkMvpView.getContext(), 0, e.getMessage());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(TalkService.TalkResultModel talkResultModel) {
                        CreateTalkPresenter.this.talkResultModel = talkResultModel;
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

I'm using retrofit 2.1.0 and rx android in this case.
So if someone have any idea, what I'm doing wrong in my code. Please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`talkService` isn't a mock. Even though you have this set:

```
@Mock
TalkService talkService;
```

You then overwrite it in your `@Before` method `setUp`:

```
talkService = ServiceFactory.createMapi(createTalkMvpView.getContext(), TalkService.class);
```

So in your test, this happens to a real `TalkService` implementation:

```
when(talkService.createNewTalk(/* ... */
    )).thenReturn(Observable.just(talkResultModel));
```

Which then calls a real `createNewTalk` method, which starts with this:

```
mApiTalkService = ServiceFactory.createMapi(
    createTalkMvpView.getContext(), TalkService.class);
```

The rest of the method isn't important, because [Mockito's `when` works by mocking the last method that was called before/within the call to `when`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14447878/1426891), and nothing else in that method interacts with mocks. If `talkService` were a mock, then `when(talkService.createNewTalk(/*...*/))` would stub the method `createNewTalk`, but instead it stubs that last mock method call `getContext`. This makes it look like:

```
when(createTalkMvpView.getContext()).thenReturn(Observable.just(talkResultModel));
```

...which exactly matches your error message:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:
>   ScalarSynchronousObservable cannot be returned by getContext()

---

To fix this, just remove your `talkService` assignment so the `when` method call is actually a mock, or use a real `talkService` as you've initialized it and remove the `@Mock` annotation and `when` and `verify` statements.

Comment: I see,
Thanks for your help
I'll try your suggestion first