# Mockito stub static method which calls a method on an object

Tags: java, mockito

There is a `Service` class and a `Util` class with two *static* methods as shown.

```
public class Service {
    public String doSomething() {
        return "something";
    }
}

public final class Util {
    public static String utilFuncCallingService(Service service) {
        //some code
        System.out.println("Util class calling doSomething on service");
        return service.doSomething();
    }
    public static String utilFuncReturningString() {
        return "string";
    }
}
```

The main class (SUT) is,

```
public class MyClass {
    public final Service service;

    public MyClass(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("Response: " + Util.utilFuncCallingService(service));
    }
}
```

It calls the `Util.utilFuncCallingService` method passing the `Service` instance.

The JUnit test is:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(Util.utilFuncCallingService(service))
                .thenReturn("mock-response");
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(service);

        myClass.method();
    }
}
```

Running this, it prints,

```
Util class calling doSomething on service
Util class calling doSomething on service
Response: mock-response
```

The first line was printed during `setup` of test and the second during actual test.

1. How did the stub call `when(Util.utilFuncCallingService(service)).thenReturn(..)` become equivalent of writing `when(service.doSomething()).thenReturn("mock-response")` here?

Mockito wouldn't have allowed us to stub `Util.utilFuncReturningString()` since it is a static method. How did the stub call to `Util.utilFuncCallingService()` work here?

I've worked with JUnit quite a lot, but I feel I'm missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few parts of to the question.

First, Mockito does support mocking static methods.

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        try(MockedStatic<Util> dummyStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Util.class)) {
            dummyStatic.when(() -> Util.utilFuncCallingService(service)).thenReturn("mock-response");
            MyClass myClass = new MyClass(service);
            myClass.method();
        }
    }
}

// Prints: Response: mock-response
```

Second, what went wrong with your test and why Mockito did not complain?

You need to know that Mockito stubbing is a stack-based machine - if you call a method on a mock inside when invoking `Mockito.when`, this call is registered on a stack, thus mockito knows which method to stub.

In your test, you called `Util.utilFuncCallingService(service)` which got executed, which in turn called `service.doSomething()` - this is a method call on a mock, so it landed on the stack. There were no other method calls on mocks, so the suubbed method is `service.doSomething()`

Observe:

```java
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(Util.utilFuncCallingService(service)).thenReturn("mock-response");
        System.out.println(service.doSomething());
    }
}

// Prints:
// Util class calling doSomething on service
// mock-response
```

You may take a look at:

- [Explanation how proxy based Mock Frameworks work](http://blog.rseiler.at/2014/06/explanation-how-proxy-based-mock.html)
- [How does mockito when() invocation work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14440270/how-does-mockito-when-invocation-work)
- [How do Mockito matchers work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22822512/how-do-mockito-matchers-work)

Comment: I didn't know this is how Mockito worked (like registering calls on stacks). Couldn't find proper documentation related to this at https://site.mockito.org/

Comment: @user7 I added a few references in my answer