# Mockito single stepping fails?

Tags: java, mockito

Ok this is weird.  Mockito, Java, on windows.

```
 when(mongoTemplate.findAndModify(any(Query.class), any(Update.class), any(FindAndModifyOptions.class), eq(Task.class)))
            .thenReturn(t1)
            .thenReturn(t2);
```

Now if I run this in debug mode it works fine. But if I put a break point on the when, and single step it fails.

The error in IntelliJ is

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Task cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String
***
If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing. 
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
 - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

So this is possibly some interaction with IntelliJ wanting to "toString()" the result while single stepping. Maybe Mockito needs to catch and fallback on toString on OngoingStubbing?

Comment: Debugging is a "heavy intervention" into "concurrency" ..(you "suspend" something)..and yes, having some "Watches" or "Variables" can also issue `toString()`.

Comment: @xerx593 multiple `thenReturn`s set up results returned from consecutive calls. First call will return first value, second call will return second value. Third call will return first again (IIRC)

Comment: @knittl Close, the last call will repeat forever as long as you don't override it with another later matching call to `when`. You can have `.thenReturn(t1, t2)`, or `.thenReturn(t1).thenReturn(t2)` as above, or even interleave `thenThrow` or `thenAnswer`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This behavior is intentional, and has to be, or else `toString` would be unstubbable or unusable.

Mockito stubbing works via [side-effects and proxying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14440270/1426891). For a call like yours:

```java
 when(mongoTemplate.findAndModify(any(Query.class), any(Update.class), any(FindAndModifyOptions.class), eq(Task.class)))
            .thenReturn(t1)
            .thenReturn(t2);
```

Mockito takes advantage of the predictable Java execution order, which evaluates method arguments in order and then the method call itself, so it sees:

1. `any(Query.class)`: 1 matcher on the [argument matcher stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22822512/1426891), return `null`
2. `any(Update.class)`: 2 matchers on the stack, return `null`
3. `any(FindAndModifyOptions.class)`: 3 matchers on the stack, return `null`
4. `eq(Task.class)`: 4 matchers on the stack, return `null`
5. `findAndModify(null, null, null, null)`: Return what `findAndModify` returns, `findAndModify` is now the most recent call
6. `when`: we're now mocking most recent call `findAndModify` with four argument matchers, reset the stack
7. `thenReturn(t1)`: Add an action onto the stubbing chain that `when` returned
8. `thenReturn(t2)`: Add an action onto the stubbing chain that `when` returned

If your IDE calls `toString` between steps 5 and 6, then Mockito will assume that you called `findAndModify(null, null, null, null)` intentionally earlier and are trying to [stub `toString`](https://groups.google.com/g/mockito/c/y8Pou35-TBw/m/XG4zBIM-CG0J) now. Since you're trying to return `t1`, that means that Mockito will tell you that your stub of `toString()` expects a String but receives a Task.

Though this is annoying, it's arguably less annoying than if Mockito refused to stub `toString()`, or if you were entirely unable to call `toString()` on a mock.